# Firefox opens random urls - which i have not accessed before

Tags: firefox

I use firefox for browsing, Ubuntu - 11.04 . Off lately it is behaving strangely. When i open a new instance of the browser, it opens random urls in new tabs which i have not visited before. Does any one know why this is happening ? Could it be a virus ? I thought Ubuntu was virus free. Are there any good antivirus software for Ubuntu ?

Comment: Would you mind sharing what some of the URLs are? Is it possible that they are for add-ons that you didn't realize you had installed?

Comment: Also are you the only user on this computer? Is it one account per person or one account per machine? is your account password protected?

Comment: The url changes each time. Here is the latest one - http://737577319 . It loads some text which looks like it is in some chinese language. I have not installed any addons recently. I also removed firefox from  my comp, cleared all  my profile data and installed it again. But this issue is still happening.

Comment: Yes , i am the only user. There is only 1 account on this laptop and only i use it. It is password protected

Comment: Does it happen when you restart in "safe mode" found by clicking on "help" in the menu?

Comment: @vasa1 Yes it happens if i start in safe mode also.

Comment: I feel your problem has more to do with Firefox than with Ubuntu. You may consider posting over here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1712247 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Lets try to debug this. If you start firefox from the terminal, and use a new profile, does the problem persist ?

```
firefox -P
```

If so, then the problem is more likely with your DNS or internet provider. Try using OpenDNS

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/how-to-switch-to-opendns-in-ubuntu-for-faster-browsing/

If the problem does not persist in a new profile, then your user profile is either corrupt of perhaps a malicious script.

In that case, personally, I would make a new profile and use NoScript

Take a look at securing firefox

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=671604

Answer (score 0):

The IP address you posted belongs to a Japanese company called Accelia, which runs a Content Delivery Network. [According to Google](http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=AS:17686), none of the websites in their network are malicious.

Now, because you say it happens when you open a new instance of the browser, the first thing you should check is the start page. To do this, open Firefox and pick Edit -> Preferences from the main menu. In the settings window, check what is the current Home Page, and if it's something you are unaware of, then click "Restore to Default".

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I have set the start page to blank. I have also enabled the option where firefox opens the tabs that were open, the last time firefox was running. On starting firefox again, it opens these tabs. Along with these, it opens a new tab as well which loads these urls.